# How to filter results by max value of price in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have problem by filtering max price into ng-repeat, this is my code:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
  <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="maxPrice">
  <label for="icon_prefix">Filtra per prezzo massimo</label>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 l4"
         ng-repeat="result in results | max:{result.PREZZO<=maxPrice}">
```

whats the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of 2 solutions,

1) Create a custom filter

**js**

```
$scope.customFilter = function(result){
    if(result.PREZZO <= $scope.maxPrice){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l4" ng-repeat="result in results | filter:customFilter></div>
```

2) You can loop through and filter your list on ng-change of your maxPrice and use the filtered array in your ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom filter for that. (I don't know if `max` is your custom filter?)

You can read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Another way is simply by using `ng-if`:

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l4" ng-repeat="result in results" ng-if="result.PREZZO <= maxPrice">
```

Comment: If you compare numbers, it should work. Decimal or not it is the same for javascript. Check an example: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8bup0n62/5/)

Comment: I think the problem is that I take the price value from mysql db because dont work!

Comment: For performance reasons, it is  better to use a custom filter. Using both `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` involve the construction and destruction of child scopes and watchers.

Comment: @georgeawg thanks for your comment. Isn't filtering in ng-repeat also bad performance-wise ? (as it runs twice in every digest cycle).  I think that the best for performance for that case is the second suggestion of NTP's answer, do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`ng-if`** directly in this case

```html
<div class="input-field col s6">
  <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
  <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="maxPrice">
  <label for="icon_prefix">Filtra per prezzo massimo</label>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m6 l4" ng-repeat="result in results" ng-if="result.PREZZO <= maxPrice"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: For performance reasons, it is  better to use a custom filter. Using both `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` involve the construction and destruction of child scopes and watchers.